# get file from src/test/resources using getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java

[image: file structure here]

++add
i want to validate json based on json schema file.
I currently save json as string , and try to read json schema file(which is test.json), then validate.
however, reading schema file is always null..

below code are I tried so far.

++original post.

this is my current situaction.
I've tried many ways to get the file(test.json)...

like

```
InputStream in;
    
     

1.  in= valid.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json"); 
2.  in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
3.   in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("//test.json");
4. in=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.json"); 
    
5. in=ValidationUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("../resources/ds/test.json"); 
    
6. ClassLoader classLoader =  getClass().getClassLoader();
   in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
7.in=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ds/test.json"); //tried just now


System.out.println("in"+in); //this is always null.
```

nothing.. work.. above..
please help me...

Comment: is the file exist on the generated jar?

Comment: hi @BagusTesa , how can i know this file is exist on the generated jar? sorry i am very new....

Comment: Could you show us your project structure?

Comment: "how can i know this file is exist on the generated jar?" Open Jar file with WinZip or any zip readers. Jar is Zip file.

Comment: @chriopp please click' file structure here'

Comment: more questions: what IDE do you use? Structure looks like Maven do you use it with your IDE? where do you need this file to be available - for JUnit or else?

Comment: @vadim thanks!  , yes this file is in the generated jar...

Comment: then  - is it in the root directory inside jar file?

Comment: @vadim  IDE: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) maven. i want test.json file to be unser src/test/resources. this is my practice project...

Comment: @Vadim sad.jar\resources\da\test.json  like this..

Comment: so it must be available through `in=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/da/test.json"); `

Comment: @Vadim thanks , i resolved the problem. >< have a nice day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (by default) access `src/test/resources` resources from code within `src/main/java`. All `src/test/resources` resources are only available for tests usually stored in `src/test/java` and executed during `test` phase (in Maven). During that phase, **test** code can access that resources by some (not all) of the methods you quoted in your question.

For your main classes, the resources root is `src/main/resources`. You should store your JSON schema file there. Test code can also access resources stored there (so no duplication needed), but not vice versa.

Comment: thank you so much...!!! i create a new folder and put my file. it works...  have a grate day

Answer (score 0):

When getting resources, the resources folder is the root. If the file is in a subfolder, you need to include it in your path. Use

```
in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ds/test.json");
```

Comment: still null...  i copied and pasted yours but still null

Comment: you are right, i just put in worng folder like @Florian Albrecht said. thanks !!!!!